# .NET MAUI Binding Issue

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Newbie to .NET MAUI and to MVVM. I've seen other examples out there for this, but mine won't work.  When I run the code it shows the string PlayProperty in PlayMCanvas as null.  I don't know how to get data into the canvas.

VM

```cs
public class ShowViewModel
{
    public string TheString {get;set; }
    public ShowViewModel()
    {
        TheString = "test";
    }
}
```

View Code Behind

```cs
public partial class ShowPlay : ContentPage
{
    public ShowViewModel TheVM;
    public ShowPlay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TheVM = new ShowViewModel();

        TheVM.TheString = "test2";
        
        BindingContext = TheVM;
    }
}
```

XAML View

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:PlayMApp.Drawables"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayMApp"
             x:Class="PlayMApp.ShowPlay"
             x:DataType="local:ShowViewModel"        
             Title="Show Play">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        
        <Button 
            Text="Add Motion"
            Clicked="AddMotion" 
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
        
        <GraphicsView HeightRequest="300"
              WidthRequest="400">
            <GraphicsView.Drawable>
                <drawables:PlayMCanvas Play="{ Binding TheString }" />
            </GraphicsView.Drawable>
        </GraphicsView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

PlayMCanvas

```cs
public class PlayMCanvas : GraphicsView, IDrawable
{
    public PlayMCanvas()
    {
    }

    public string Play
    {
        get  => (string)GetValue(PlayProperty);
        set => SetValue(PlayProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty PlayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Play), typeof(string), typeof(PlayMCanvas));

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
        canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100); 
        canvas.DrawString(Play,40,30,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }
}
```

When I get to the final line (DrawString), I think Play should be "test2", but it's null

I've tried making changes to the code to tweak what is sent in.  If I send just a plain literal string through the `<drawables:PlayMCanvas Play="test" />`, it works, but not with the binding

Comment: Your ViewModel needs to either implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or inherit from a base class that does, e.g. `ObservableObject` from the MVVM Community Toolkit. Otherwise, no `PropertyChanged` events are raised and thus no property changes are propagated to the View.

Comment: That shouldn’t matter in this case as he is assigning the VM properties before he sets the BindingContext.  OP do you really have all that white space in your binding expression?

Comment: @Jason Ah yes, you're right, but no changes will be propagated either way. Indeed, the whitespace is not allowed. It should be `Play="{Binding TheString}"`.

Comment: I’ll add to the above: When run, does VS Output pane have a warning about that Play attribute having bad value? That would be clue about what needs to change, as described above.

Comment: I tried removing the white space, adding the INotifyPropertyChanged (and added "public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;" to VM), and moving the assignment to after the BindingContext and Play is still null.  If nothing else, shouldn't it set the TheString to "test" in the ShowViewModel constructor and bind it with that value even if there is no propertychanged getting fired?  It's showing Play as null even if i remove the "TheVM.TheString = "test2";" line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, saw another example where someone was very specific in the component they were binding to and followed that.

Added `x:Name` to the `PlayMCanvas` like below:

```
<drawables:PlayMCanvas x:Name="PlayMCan" Play="{Binding TheString}" />
```

Changed to this in codebehind:

```
PlayMCan.BindingContext = TheVM;
```

And now the binding seems to be working.

Thanks for the comments!